# gantt type plot combined with bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, gantt-chart

I have this data set

```
work_time_nurses <- list(
    list(name='Nurse 1', level=1, start= 8:00, end= 17:00),
    list(name='Nurse 2', level=1, start= 8:00, end= 17:00),
    list(name='Nurse 3', level=2, start= 12:00, end= 20:30),
    list(name='Nurse 4', level=3, start= 18:00, end= 1:00 )

operations_time <- list(
         list(name='Operations 1', level=1, start= 8:00, count = 10),
         list(name='Operations 2', level=1, start= 9:00, count = 9),
         list(name='Operations 3', level=1, start= 10:00, count= 5),
         list(name='Operations 4', level=1, start= 12:00, count= 9),
         list(name='Operations 5', level=1, start= 13:00, count= 0),
         list(name='Operations 6', level=1, start= 14:00, count= 0),
         list(name='Operations 7', level=1, start= 15:00, count= 9),
         list(name='Operations 8', level=1, start= 16:00, count= 10),
         list(name='Operations 9', level=1, start= 17:00, count= 8),
         list(name='Operations 10', level=1, start= 18:00, count= 5)
```

List "work_time_nurses" is work time of nurses and list "operations_time" is number of operations, that starts in given time.

I would like to graphically represent distribution of operations during a day and time capacities od nurses. Graph would show that peek of operations is understaffed or overstaffed.

In the graph there should be a time period and bar plot of operations on x-axis and on one y-axis should be staff (Nurse 1.... Nurse 4) and their schedule and second y-axis should be numer of operations.

Is it possible to plot something like this?

Edit:

I plot something like gantt plot like this

```
ggplot(work_time_nurses, aes(x= name, fill = level))+
      geom_rect(aes(x = name, xmin = as.numeric(name) - 0.45, xmax =        as.numeric(name) + 0.45, ymin = start, ymax = end))+
      coord_flip()
```

It somehow works as schedule, but I do not understand it well.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I just edit my question.

Comment: @onhalu Take a look at the `vistime` package - would this be something to consider? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vistime/vignettes/vistime-vignette.html

Comment: Thank you I consider it.